# Is it possible to have a pdf document as format for crystal report?

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports

I am just wondering if I can have a pdf document as a format for crystal report

situation 
I have a form in a pdf format where I must fill up the blanks and I wanted my program will fill the form using crystal report because eventually i have to print the particular form

reason 
the form has so many data and questions to imitate

Answer (score 1):

A potential way to accomplish your end result (PDF populated with data, printed to paper) would be to:

1. export the PDF as an image (there are several [printer drivers](https://www.google.ca/search?q=print%20to%20image&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=l10xUoLWHuvoiwLYooDoCg) that can do this)
2. import the image into the Crystal Report - note this is really only a temporary step to help with layout
3. Arrange your data fields over the blanks in your form

For better print output quality, I recommend removing the image from the report at this point, and printing to each page twice (first for the PDF template, then over top of that with the Crystal Report data, which is now happily arranged exactly where the blank spots are on your page).